# Простой-сложный select

Tags: mysql, sql

таблица: `m_frend` дружит со `sl_frend` (в примере 883 дружит с 876), НО есть записи в которых другие `uid`'ы дружат с `m_frend` (то есть в таком случае  `m_frend` будет `sl_frend`'ом). Пример 856 дружит с 883.

```
mysql> select * from frends ;
+---------+----------+-------+
| m_frend | sl_frend | fr_st |
+---------+----------+-------+
|     883 |      876 |     1 |
|     880 |      875 |     1 |
|     881 |      877 |     1 |
|     856 |      883 |     1 |
|     859 |      883 |     1 |
|     860 |      883 |     1 |
|     883 |      879 |     1 |
|     883 |      880 |     1 |
|     883 |      881 |     2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Нужно в одном запросе, ОДНИМ СТОЛБИКОМ, вытянуть всех друзей 883 (тех с кем дружит 883), и ТЕХ КТО ДРУЖИТ С 883.

Такой вот калмбурчик вышел, надеюсь продлему описал понятно. И реально ли это сделать (получить результат в одном стобце)?

---

Знаю что можно сначала получить

```
mysql> select * from frends where m_frend=883 or sl_frend=883;
+---------+----------+-------+
| m_frend | sl_frend | fr_st |
+---------+----------+-------+
|     883 |      876 |     1 |
|     856 |      883 |     1 |
|     859 |      883 |     1 |
|     860 |      883 |     1 |
|     883 |      879 |     1 |
|     883 |      880 |     1 |
|     883 |      881 |     2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

а потом в коде отбросить 883. но как результат запроса получить одним столбцом?

*Я не знаю какой заголовок дать этому вопросу.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких задач отлично подходит конструкция [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). Запрос с ее использованием может иметь вот такой вид:

```
SELECT sl_frend AS frend_id FROM frends WHERE m_frend = 883
    UNION SELECT m_frend AS frend_id FROM frends WHERE sl_frend = 883;
```

А вот и SQL Fiddle с [рабочим примером](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27ee7/1).

Comment: хм-м, так просто. Я так понял благодаря AS стообЦЫ переименовывается в frend_id (!), ну а дальше мне все как-бэ  понятно.

Comment: Основной момент здесь все-таки в `UNION` а не в `AS`

Comment: спорить не буду. но суть (наверное) уловил.  ДВА запроса возвращают зачения в стобец с одним именем. И откуда люди об этом (о mySQL) знают?

Answer (score 2):

Тут с одной стороны все понятно с UNION.
Но посмотрите немного глубже.
Структура таблиц не соответсвует принципам реляционных баз данных.
Чем у Вас левый товарищ может отличаеться от правого? Они же совершенно равноправны.
Тут лучше использовать такую структуру
Люди (ИД)
Отношение товарищества (ИД)
Товарищи (ИД_Отношения_товарищества, ИД_Человека)

Конечно, тут придется использовать  цже не UNION, а JOIN.

Comment: НЕЕТ! Это таблица дружественных отношений. ВСЯ ДРУЖБА уже абсоолютно верно обраабатывается и вывод кнопок в профиле тоже уже железно написан. Все так как должно быть.. Отличия в том что левый товарищ первым подает заявку в друзья второму (правому товарищу.)

Comment: повторюсь:"Чем у Вас левый товарищ может отличаеться от правого? Они же совершенно равноправны. " - они НЕ равноправны. Ведь называются столбцы по-разному, и очевидно что в суть названия столбцов заложен некий смысл. А те отношения о которых вы написали - это ( ужасный темный лес. ну... эээ... я сделал так как сделал - все отлично работает! Для дружбы есть  две таблички.(оптимизация, чтобы дишнее не хранить в тбл дружбы и проще был код) ВТОРАЯ без третьего поля, ТОЛЬКО два ИД, но поля тоже по разному называются - это тбл "блэлист" - все очень просто обрабатывается - заявка в друзья, блокировка

Answer (score 1):

```
select case m_frend when 883 then sl_frend else m_frend end as frend
from frends
where m_frend = 883 or sl_frend = 883
```

Comment: ваш пример чуть посложнее., но тоже работает!